# I want to use IHttpClientFactory with Prism

Tags: c#

In a WPF application using Prism (.NET Core3.1, DryIoc), I want to define and get IHttpClientFactory in the constructor of ViewModel of the main screen, but the following exception occurs in the InitializeComponent () method of the constructor of View of the main screen. appear.

---

Internal exception 1:
ContainerResolutionException: An unexpected error occurred while resolving'SamplePrismDryIocApp.ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel'

Internal exception 2:
ContainerException: code: Error.UnableToResolveUnknownService;
message: Unable to resolve Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceScopeFactory as parameter "scopeFactory" (IsSingletonOrDependencyOfSingleton)
in Resolution root Singleton Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory {DryIoc.IfUnresolved.ReturnDefaultIfNotRegistered} FactoryId = 168 (IsSingletonOrDependencyOfSingleton, IsResolutionCall)
from container without scope

---

The APP class defines as follows, but what should I do with the container definition of "IServiceScopeFactory" above?

---

```
public partial class App: PrismApplication
{
    protected override Window CreateShell ()
    {
        return Container.Resolve <MainWindow> ();
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes (IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterServices (s => {
            s.AddHttpClient ();
        });
    }
}
```

---

The installed packages are as follows.

-Microsoft.Extensions.Http (5.0.0)

-Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Polly (5.0.1)

-Prism.Container.Extensions (8.0.62)

-Prism.DryIoc (8.0.0.1909)

Comment: `HttpClient` is in `System.Net.Http`, you likely need to add that.

Comment: Thank you for your advice  <br/>

The specification information of the basic framework was leaked. 
It is as follows. 
--Microsoft.NETCore.App  
--Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF  
The above "Microsoft .NET Core.App" framework included "System.Net.Http".  
Therefore, I don't think it is the problem you pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

`Prism.Container.Extensions` is `Prism + DryIoc + WPF` not support.

[Please provide a sample WPF application using Prism.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.Extensions #157](https://github.com/dansiegel/Prism.Container.Extensions/issues/157)

I have a wrapper library that converts an IServiceCollection to a corresponding container and registers it in an environment such as Prism where the container settings cannot be changed.

[DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.Extension](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.Extension/)

I made a sample.

[20210525_PrismDryIocHttpClientSample](https://github.com/juner/20210525_PrismDryIocHttpClientSample)

Comment: Your package worked for me when a few of the other common packages intended for same thing did not. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following measures were taken as countermeasures.

### -- Define a POJO class with service provider properties.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class ServiceControl
{
    public ServiceProvider SvcProvider {get; private set;}

    public ServiceControl (ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.SvcProvider
        = serviceProvider;
    }
}
```

---

### -- Define a static method in the App class that creates a service provider for HttpClientFactory.

```
public static ServiceControl GetServiceControl ()
{
    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection ();
    services.AddHttpClient ();
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider ();
    
    return new ServiceControl (serviceProvider);
}
```

---

### -- Register the return value of the GetServiceControl method in the RegisterTypes method.

```
protected override void RegisterTypes (IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{

    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton <ServiceControl> (GetServiceControl);

}
```

---

### -- Get an instance of ServiceControl from the constructor of the ViewModel to be used and use IHttpClientFactory as shown below.

```
(
...
ServiceControl serviceControl,
...
)

IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory = serviceControl.SvcProvider.GetRequiredService <IHttpClientFactory> ();
```

---

With the above, IHttpClientFactory can be used.